# What is the meaning of "that it is" here?

Tags: grammar

> You can tell that the capitalist system is in trouble when people start talking about capitalism. It indicates that the system has ceased to be as natural as the air we breathe, and can be seen instead as the historically rather recent phenomenon **that it is**.

> We are fortunate **that it is**, because new educational systems there and putting enough people through them to improve economic performance would require two or three generations.

Is "that it is" trying to emphasize its antecedent?

Comment: The second example is not the structure you're asking about. It's *[ "that" + clause ]*, and by coincidence, the clause happens to have the words, "it is", where "it" is an ordinary pronoun, and "is" is an ordinary verb.

Comment: @gotube OK..., but what is the structure of the first example trying to imply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure *[ "the" + noun + "(that) it is" ]* emphasizes the fact that it is X.

We often use this to strongly assert something that we're not confident the audience accepts, particularly with strongly held opinions that we're trying to get others to agree with. It's often used in political speeches and other places where people rally support for their cause or opinion.

> Drea says that she'll spike the dinner with some mushrooms and expose Carissa for the criminal that she is.
> (*from a movie, "Do Revenge"*)

Just from this sentence, we can infer that not everyone agrees or knows Carissa is a criminal, but it's really important to Drea that everyone believes this.

So in your context, the speaker is asserting that capitalism is a historically rather recent phenomenon, that it's important to them that the audience agrees with this, and that they're unsure if they will.